# Need to Convert a hierarchical JSON into a rowspaned html table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a JSON structure like

```
$scope.data = [
        {
            "type":"Internal",
            "count": 3,
            "library" : [
                {
                "type":"Library 123",
                "count": 2,
                "version" : ["1.3","2.3"]
                },
                {
                "type":"Library 1111",
                "count": 1,
                "version" : ["556.3"]
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "type":"External",
            "count": 3,
            "library" : [
                {
                "type":"Library 09090909",
                "count": 2,
                "version" : ["1.3","2.3"]
                },
                {
                "type":"Library 1212121212",
                "count": 1,
                "version" : ["556.3"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and i need to convert it into a html table.  for e.g., Internal spans into 3 rows as specified in the count variable. What I tried to do in html is

```
<table>

    <div ng-repeat="row in data">
        {{$root.rowFirst=true;""}}
        <div ng-repeat="lib in row.library" >
            {{$root.libFirst=true;""}}
            <div ng-repeat="ver in lib.version">
                <tr>

                    <td ng-if="$root.rowFirst" rowspan="{{row.count}}">{{row.type}}  {{$root.rowFirst=false;""}}</td>
                    <td ng-if="$root.libFirst" rowspan="{{lib.count}}">{{lib.type}}  {{$root.libFirst=false;""}}</td>
                    <td>{{ver}}</td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </table>
```

but i got an angularjs infdig error. can anyone help me to build the html table.

Final result should be something like this

```
                                  1.3
                  Library 123     2.3   
Internal          Library 1111    556.3


                                  1.3
                  Library 123     2.3   
External          Library 1111    556.3
```

Comment: table>**div>div**>tr>td looks weird..
table>tbody>tr>td

Comment: provide your code on JSfiddle

Comment: what is this supposed to do? `$root.rowFirst=false;""` your infinite digest probably comes from that thing

Comment: here is the jsfiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/7gwqc8dh/

Comment: $root.rowFirst=false; is used because for each iteration in <div ng-repeat="row in data"> row data needs to be put into the <tr> once. so after adding first time, need to exclude it the second because it spans for 3 rows.again when a new iteration begins again need to add to so that value to set to true ({{$root.rowFirst=true;""}}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping in the view (html), I iterate each inside the controller and built a new single array containing all the information i need

```
    $scope.dataMod = [];
    var newType , newLib, tempObj;

    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(type, key) {
          newType =true ;
          angular.forEach(type.library, function(lib, key) {
            newLib = true;
            angular.forEach(lib.version, function(ver, key) {
                tempObj = {};
                if(newType) {
                    tempObj.typeName = type.type;
                    tempObj.typeCount = type.count;
                    newType=false;
                }
                if(newLib) {
                    tempObj.libName = lib.type;
                    tempObj.libCount = lib.count;
                    newLib=false;
                }
                tempObj.version = ver;
                $scope.dataMod.push(tempObj);

            });

          });
    });
```

and in the html

```
    <table border="1" width="100%"  >
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataMod">
            <td ng-if="data.typeCount" rowspan="{{data.typeCount}}">{{data.typeName}}</td>
            <td ng-if="data.libCount" rowspan="{{data.libCount}}">{{data.libName}} </td>
            <td> {{data.version}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```